# Angular 2 - input binding to callback method reference

Tags: angular

I want a modal component to run a method that is passed to it with data binding. My intention is that when the modal is dismissed it will call a method that is a reference to a method of the parent component. What is the correct NG2 way to do so?

For example I want the following structure:

Parent component html has this:

```
<some-modal-tag [callbackMethod]="parentComponentMethod"><some-modal-tag/>
```

And in the child modal that answers to  component I want to do something like this:

```
@Input: callbackMethod;
onDismiss(){
  run(callbackMethod,args[]);
}
```

Comment: That is pretty much the same thing, but the accepted answer here is (in my opinion) clearer. It shows exactly the simplest use mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `@Output()` in your modal:

```
@Output() dismiss = new EventEmitter();
private onDismiss(){
  // on close button click, or whatever closes this modal
  this.dismiss.emit('I'm dismissed.');
}
```

and in your component's template:

```
<some-modal-tag (dismiss)="parentComponentMethod($event)"><some-modal-tag/>
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<some-modal-tag [callbackMethod]="parentComponentMethod()"><some-modal-tag/>

@Input: callbackMethod;
  onDismiss(){
  callbackMethod();
}

parentComponentMethod() {
 return () => {
  // Your code here
 }
}
```

*NOTE the use of arrow function to retain closed scope, without it the callback will work inconsistently

Comment: This answer actually answers straight to what I was looking for so thanks a lot! but after reading some, I understand that @Sasxa 's answer is the more correct in terms of correct Angular 2 practice. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the fat arrow's role here? I don't understand why it is necessary.

Comment: For example if the component have a property `foo`. The calling component also have property `foo` or worse doesnt have it. `this.foo` inside the function will be the child components foo or undefined respectively.